# Facebook “No Internet Connection” for mobile app

Tags: iphone, facebook, oauth, oauth-2.0, facebook-oauth

I used mobile version Authentication to get access token for Facebook.
I use like this.

The problem occurs in `iPhone`. `Other mobile devices as far as OK`.

```
https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/authorize?type=user_agent&display=wap&client_id=12345&redirect_uri=www.blahblah.com/blah&scope=user_photos,read_stream,publish_stream,offline_access,user_status,friends_status
```

but it hits `"No Internet Connection"` . Actually, the account was log into Facebook.

Any particular things that I miss in Authentication?

Answer (score 0):

Please try passing `display=touch` instead of `display=wap`.
This seemed to resolve the issue for me.